# How to unify input format with Google Email Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, number-formatting

I am using this google-email-script below to send some data by mail from a google sheet.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails

**My problem** 
There are different people putting information in the sheet. Depending how the data are entered into the sheet, its changing the formatting of the field. For example percentage data changed to decimal formatting `[6.98% -> 0.0698]`. Other people give the data already in decimal format with no `%` Symbol.

Is there a way to unify the both ways to input the data?

**My script**

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 300;   // Number of rows to process

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5) 
// Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var message = 'Hi ' + row[2] + '\n'
   + 'text before data,' + row[3] + 'text after data.'
   + '\n\n'
   +'more text data'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO...I try to improve your question in terms of language and style on this side. Please have a look [here][https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve] and [here][https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask]. For example you can be more specific what dont work in your script and add some sample data.

Answer (score 2):

[getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue()):

> Returns the value of the top-left cell in the range. The value may be of type **Number**, Boolean, Date, or String depending on the value of the cell.

So the script's `getValue()` will always read the percent value as a decimal number [use [getDisplayValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValue()) to get what is displayed in the sheet]

If you only need the value to show as a percent **in the email**, change the `getValue() | data[i][3]` number into a percent by `* 100`.

```
var message = 'Hi ' + row[2] + '\n'
+ 'text before data,' + (row[3] * 100) + '%' + ' text after data.'
+ '\n\n'
+'more text data'
```